# azure slot swapping not respecting 'sticky' settings for webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-deployment-slots

I have an Azure production app slot and a staging app slot.  Ive set the app specific items as 'sticky' in production and staging (connection strings, keys, etc)

when I flip between production and staging, my webjob settings are taking the staging slot settings which is disastrous (I found out the hard way in a live site !)

the connection string names and the keys all have the same names in the web app and all the web jobs (web.config & app.config) so why would this be happening ?

I now have to manually publish from my development environment which is not ideal.  One thing I have noticed is that previously when I selected my live app and did the swap, the name stayed as my live app name, but now it always defaults to 'production' which i dont have.  It seems that Azure will use this for the main app service.  This didnt happen before and when i swapped slots it worked perfectly.  Is there anything else i need to be aware of ?  Has the slot swapping process changed somehow ?

Comment: If you check the environment tab in Kudu, does it have the correct values for those settings or is it also wrong? Note that 'production' is the implied name of the slot for the live site, so that is normal behavior.

Comment: I've set the production and staging settings accordingly, yet when I swap slots then check the app.config settings in the web jobs, they always have the settings from staging

Comment: Previous question still stands to help isolate.

Comment: in Kudu the keys are correct but there connection strings arent

Comment: Not able to repro this. Can you edit your question with detailed step by step on how you are getting into this situation? Starting with the time you add the conn string on each slot, mark it as sticky, do the swap, check the value. The more detailed the better to avoid further misunderstandings.